# Calculate Reordering Point in R

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to create an algorithm that can help me calculate reording point (ROP) based on:

- Ordering Dates (OD)
- Delivery Dates (DD)
- Store Forecast (Fcst)

I have been trying for weeks but cannot find the way to do this efficiently because I will be running this simulations for 1 million item-store combinations.

The logic is simple:

We have to sum the forecast from the nearest delivery date upto the following delivery date. (Starting from the ordering dates)

**Nearest delivery date will never be the same ordering date**

The example:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)

sim_days   <- 30
start_Date <- as.Date("2022-01-01")
seq_days   <- seq.Date(start_Date,start_Date + 30, by="days")

OD <- c(0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1)
DD <- c(0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0)
Forecast <- c(100,230,300,417,170,414,430,331,320,121,172,161,340,234,369,274,351,447,233,372,427,174,328,143,193,235,104,233,404,219,268)
Expected_Result <- c("","",1014,"","",1202,"","",293,907,"","",877,"","","",1032,"","",1500,"","","",572,"","",1124,"","","","")

OD <- rbind(as.character(seq_days),as.numeric(OD)); colnames(OD) <- as.character(seq_days); OD <- OD[-1,]
DD <- rbind(as.character(seq_days),as.numeric(DD)); colnames(DD) <- as.character(seq_days); DD <- DD[-1,]
rbind(OD,DD,Forecast,Expected_Result)[]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach, which starts by putting your data into a data.table:

```
df = data.table(
  date=seq_days, OD = OD, DD=DD,Forecast = Forecast
)
```

Now, we first add the forecast sum for each delivery date, which includes the sum of Forecast from that date to the next delivery date:

```
df[,ind:=cumsum(DD)]
df[,fsum:=sum(Forecast),ind]
df[,fsum:=fifelse(ind!=shift(ind,-1),fsum+shift(Forecast,-1),fsum)]
df[,fsum:=max(fsum,na.rm=T),ind]
```

Then, create a vector of ordering dates

```
od = df[OD==1,date]
```

Finally, for each of the ordering date rows, take the forecast sum from df where `DD==1` and `OD!=1` and the date exceeds this ordering date

```
df[OD==1, result:=lapply(od, \(o) df[DD==1 & date>o,fsum[1]])][,`:=`(fsum=NULL,ind=NULL)]
```

Output:

```
          date OD DD Forecast result
 1: 2022-01-01  0  0      100       
 2: 2022-01-02  0  0      230       
 3: 2022-01-03  1  0      300   1014
 4: 2022-01-04  0  0      417       
 5: 2022-01-05  0  1      170       
 6: 2022-01-06  1  0      414   1202
 7: 2022-01-07  0  1      430       
 8: 2022-01-08  0  0      331       
 9: 2022-01-09  1  0      320    293
10: 2022-01-10  1  1      121    907
11: 2022-01-11  0  1      172       
12: 2022-01-12  0  0      161       
13: 2022-01-13  1  0      340    877
14: 2022-01-14  0  1      234       
15: 2022-01-15  1  0      369   1305
16: 2022-01-16  0  1      274       
17: 2022-01-17  1  0      351   1032
18: 2022-01-18  0  0      447       
19: 2022-01-19  0  1      233       
20: 2022-01-20  1  0      372   1500
21: 2022-01-21  0  1      427       
22: 2022-01-22  0  0      174       
23: 2022-01-23  0  0      328       
24: 2022-01-24  1  0      143    572
25: 2022-01-25  0  0      193       
26: 2022-01-26  0  1      235       
27: 2022-01-27  1  0      104   1124
28: 2022-01-28  0  1      233       
29: 2022-01-29  0  0      404       
30: 2022-01-30  0  0      219       
31: 2022-01-31  1  0      268     NA
```

Comment: 2022-01-09 should be 293 though

Comment: You changed your original question. And it still doesn’t have 293 in the expected result. If you clean that up, and make it clear what you want, I’ll adjust. Also please make it absolutely clear how you want to handle rows where OD and DD are both equal to 1

Comment: the correct number is 293 I´ve already corrected it. And I think you have the correct result up until this line of code:   df[,fsum:=max(fsum,na.rm=T),ind]

Comment: All the rows where OD and DD are equal to 1 mean that a store generates a purchase order the same day that receives orders. So im not sure how it programatically needs to be handle but the order of the date 2022-01-09 should sum the nearest forecast of the delivery date (2022-01-10) and the one rigth next to it. (2022-01-11)

Comment: okay @MaxMolina. got it. I originally had 293 in my answer, but since I didn't see it for "2022-01-09" in your original expected result, I added `& OD!=1` to the final line of my code.  If you remove that, you will get `293` in that row.

Comment: have also edited the solution - hope it does the trick for you.

Comment: I had been looking for a solution for so long, thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248336/discussion-between-max-molina-and-langtang).